# Hover event, but not on touch/mobile devices

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am trying to create a hover event that shows an image. On my desktop/laptop it fires correctly. However on a mobile (touch), the image only appears when the modal link is clicked, then it is sticky (it stays on screen).

On mobile or touch-screens, i don't want the hover event to fire.

Here is what i am working with.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/pxwd34ka/4/)

HTML

```
<a href="#test" id="test-parent">Hover to show image</a>

<img class="preview" id="test-child" src="https://mayvers.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/test-image.jpg" />

<script>
  $("#test-parent").hover(function() {
    $("#test-child").fadeToggle();
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.preview {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it is touch event or not and fire the hover effect accordingly.

```
<script>
  $("#test-parent").hover(function() {
   if(!isTouchEvent()){
    $("#test-child").fadeToggle();
   }
  });

  function isTouchEvent() {
    return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement
           || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0
           || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
  }

</script>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8qxsdLvm/)**

Answer (score 0):

from @PaulOB over at sitepoint

```
<script>
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
      $("#test-parent").hover(function() {
       $("#test-child").fadeToggle();
    });
   } 
</script>
```